# Notes 9 crashes while editing external email

Tags: crash, lotus-notes

We have a customized mail template where we can set values of a parameter in mail preference.

After getting upgraded to Notes 9, when the parameter is set to Automatic it's working fine, but when another value is selected below thing happens (It was working fine in previous versions of Notes..):

After opening any external email, after double clicking on the mail body to edit.. notes is getting crashed.

I have two questions :

1. I see for external emails the control is going from querymodechange to queryclose while editing. Does it always happen?
2. I debugged the whole thing. Surprisingly it works in debug mode..no notes crash!!

Any help would be much appreciated !!!

Answer (score 2):

This is why customizing the mail template is rarely recommended. There are interactions and dependencies between the code in the template and the Notes client, and it's very hard to debug. Since you haven't shown any of your customized code, I don't think anybody is going to be able to help you. I would recommend removing your customization code one piece at a time until it no longer crashes. Then you'll have an idea of what's triggering it, and you can try a different approach.

Comment: the code is too long to paste here...there are couple of subroutines and functions which are triggered from FormPostModeChange, FormPostOpen, FormQueryClose..mostly I could understand it's crashing in QueryClose section.
But surprisingly in debug mode it does not crash!

Comment: That doesn't surprise me at all. The debugger changes the way the code interacts with the client. You're going to have to try removing one piece at a time to see what stops the crash. Or the reverse - remove it all and add it back one piece at a time. In fact you might need to follow both approaches, because it might be a combination of two operations that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When Notes crashes, it dumps some diagnostics in the data/IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT directory, notably the file console.log
You could review it and post here the lines pertaining to the crash.

Also, what was the previous version of Notes ?

To target the offending code line, you can use that old, dirty and tedious trick : add the folling line at the top of the QueryClose event, and move it down until you no longer see the result. Then post the context.

```
print now & "so far so good"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help..I am able to narrow down the search!! :)

There is some issue with DoCloseDialog field, it's not setting as expected.
Could you please confirm that while editing external mails the control goes directly from QueryModeChange to QueryClose?? I could not see any instance of Postmodechange.. :(

Comment: This is where the notes is crashing I think!!

varResponse = wsCurrDoc.DialogBox("TLSCloseMailWindow", True, True, , , , , "Close Window", tempdoc)

Comment: After spending some time I can explain the scenario -
The code is to replace the Notes "Do you want to save your changes" pop up (while trying to close unsaved mail/doc) with a customized one in QueryClose. Now, in notes 9, the customized code for Dialog Box is crashing notes which was working in previous versions. I created a simple form for a new dialog box, and again it crashed. Any help!!